# c# WPF MVVM Set View Property From ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to create a simple Control to enter Text.
For this Control i want to create a Property.
This Property should be bind to the ViewModel.

I Created a Model for an Folder:

```
public class FolderModel : ModelBase
{
    private string fullPath;
    public string FullPath
    {
        get { return fullPath; }
        set
        {
            if (fullPath == value)
                return;
            fullPath = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullPath));
        }
    }
}
```

In my View xaml i bound the Data to my ViewModel:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Browser:FolderBrowserViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_Folder" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Folder.FullPath}"/>
</Grid>
```

To Create the Property created this code in the View:

```
public string FullPath
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FolderFullPathProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FolderFullPathProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty FolderFullPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FullPath", typeof(string), typeof(FolderBrowser), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSetTextChanged))); 
private static void OnSetTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowser UserControl1Control = d as FolderBrowser;
    UserControl1Control.OnSetTextChanged(e);
}

private void OnSetTextChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox_Folder.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
}
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
private ICommand _browseFolderCommand;
public ICommand BrowseFolderCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _browseFolderCommand is null ? (_browseFolderCommand = new RelayCommand(() => BrowseFolder(), true)) : _browseFolderCommand;
    }
}
private FolderModel folder = new FolderModel();
public FolderModel Folder
{
    get { return folder; }
    set
    {
        if (folder == value)
            return;
        folder = value;
    }
}
private void BrowseFolder()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        SetField(ref folder, Folder, "FullPath");
    }
}
```

and my ViewModelBase looks like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void Dispatch(Action f) => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(f);
    protected TResult Dispatch<TResult>(Func<TResult> f) => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(f);
}
```

if i use the Control i want to set the Property "FullPath"
when i set this Property the Value should be set to the ViewModels Folder.FullPath.
If this is set, the Binding of the TextBox and Folder.FullPath should show the correct path.

if its possible i want all Code in the ViewModel =)

**Edit:**

I tried to illustrate it a bit more pictorially:

[image]

On the left side you can see the control as it is placed on a window. There you can set MyProp to any value and the TextBox will receive it.

On the right side I have tried to show it in more detail.
The view has the label, a TextBox and a button.
The view also has the property "MyProp".
The textbox of the view is bound to the ViewModel, namely to the field "MyCoolFieldValue".

This means that if I do anything in the ViewModel with the field MyCoolFieldValue, I know that it will always have the value that is in the textbox.

If I now press the button, a command is called. This command changes the WErt of MyCoolFieldValue. When this happens, the value should be written directly back into the property and the textbox of the view.

However, I can't get this to work and have tried it with the code above.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: My Question ist: How can i Bind the Property of a User Control with my Property in my ViewModel.

Comment: Just define a Binding in XAML like you do with any other control like the TextBox in your example.

Comment: if i define a Binding in XAML the View would bind directly to my Property in my ViewModel. I Want a Property in my View which binds to the ViewModel. So i can but my Control in a Window and set the Value of a Property and the ViewModel knows the Value

Comment: Since when is it wrong to bind to the view model? That's what the view model is for. It's the data source for the view. What definitely is wrong is to allow the view model to access the view - for example to set a property.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong. I'm just trying to find a solution to synchronise my own property from the view with my ViewModel.

Comment: I want to have a control where I can have a property. This property should then be displayed in a TextBox. There should also be a button on the control. Of course, this button calls up a command in the ViewModel. This command should then change a value, which should then be displayed in the TextBox.

Later, I would like to be able to query this property again from my control and receive the value from the TextBox.

Comment: But if your Control and the TextBox depend on the same value, which is the value from the view model, then bind both to the view model. You send data from view model to view via data binding or events.

Comment: and how can i do this? :D